# Dual switched power supply circuit

Tags: power, mosfet

I'm putting together a circuit to supply power to a step down buck converter from a battery 12-15V. I would like my circuit to be "on" when a separate 12-15V circuit has power, or when a 3.3V signal from a Raspberry Pi is high.

I drew the circuit below. To my very beginner mind, it seems like it should work. Is there anything I'm missing? The diodes are there just in case the 12-15V inputs spike for some reason. Do you think I need resistors to limit current anywhere? Would some capacitance somewhere help if the inputs are noisy? (There are a bunch of capacitors in the regulator circuit.)

Datasheet for Q2: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSMN017-30PL.pdf

Datasheet for Q3: http://www.vishay.com/docs/91310/sihld120.pdf

[image: power]

Comment: FYI you can add text to KiCad schematics instead of using floating local net labels.  You'll be able to use spaces instead of underscores, and you won't have that pesky little square hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

Where to start ....

Q2 is upside down. You have its drain and source reversed and it will effectively never switch off because its body diode will always be forward biased.
But even it you turned it around, you're still using an N-Channel MOSFET as a high-side switch - which really means it's acting as a voltage follower and your output will never be higher than the gate voltage less the gate threshold voltage - so it'll never really act as a good switch (it will always have a significant voltage drop).

It gets even worse when we look at Q3. It's also upside down, but flipping it still leaves you with the high-side switch / source-follower problem.
Its Vgs(th) is specced as 1-2V, so taking the middle ground of 1.5V, and recognizing that you're applying a 3.3V control signal to its gate, means that you'll never get much more than 1.8V out when it's 'switched on'.

Comment: Thank you. The source-drain reversal was accidental. I'm going to have to read some about "the high-side switch / source-follower problem". I was largely under the impression that I could use mosfets like I would use a relay, but apparently that isn't the case.